# File Upload shows data with empty strings on Safari and Chrome iOS8.1.2

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, file-upload, safari

Hello we are having issues with File Upload on Chrome and Safari on IOS 8.1.2. Some photo upload shows data with an empty string, others are displaying OK. Anyone knows a workaround so the uploaded photos can be consistently displayed? Thanks so much.

Initially we thought that it was a known issue with File Upload featuring broken on iOS 8 Safari. "http://blog.uploadcare.com/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari/". However, It appeared to be problem with 8.0.0 and has supposedly been fixed. Also, the problem is not limited to Safari and appears in Chrome iOS as well.

Specifically, when a photo chosen was taken directly from the iPHONE camera, the data appears to be empty (see log in console)

[Log] Object (controllers.js, line 228)
src: "data:,"

However, when a photo chosen is either a Screen Shot or a photo saved from an email, the image is in fact displayed and the data is sent

[Log] Object (controllers.js, line 228)
src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+/8AAEQgGYATIAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBh...."

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Why does it work with some photos but not others? Anyone knows any workaround to display images that have been taken from the Camera itself?

---

Snippets of codes here:

```
$scope.getAlbumPicture = function() {
    Camera.getAlbumPicture().then(function(fileURI) {
        $scope.normalisePicture(fileURI, function(dataURL) {
            Local.setTemp(dataURL);
            $state.go('tab.camera-detail');
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
$scope.readImage = function(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function() {
            $scope.normalisePicture(fileReader.result, function(dataURL) {
                Local.setTemp(dataURL);
                $state.go('tab.camera-detail');
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have found that this works in the latest version of safari on ios, but chrome has trouble handling larger files on mobile. If you try this out with smaller files, it will probably work but that's not really the solution you (or me) are looking for

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Recently I encountered similar issue as described in question, found [this thread](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/294#issuecomment-99789111), it may has been a low memory issue with iPhone, and not much work around you can do but resize the big size image with canvas element, I using 1200 as the longest width/height for the image to resize then everything works again.

for any feature reference, more specific hardware and software the problem occurred with my test is iPhone 6 Plus and iOS 8.1.2, and the process I tried to do with images is:

1. using `FileReader.onLoad = func` with `FileReader.readAsDataURL()`to read `input[type="file"]`'s file as `base64` string.
2. assign `base64` as `new image()`'s `src`
3. inside `image.onload = func` draw a new `canvas`'s `2d context` with the same with and height as image above.
4. check some orientation EXIF info then rotate the canvas.
5. finally do other staffs with `base64` string of new image which generated form `canvas.toDataURL()`.

The empty `data:` occurs in both between **step 1 to step 2** and **step 5** randomly depends on the size of image got from `input[type="file"].

In my case, iOS Safari here seems being okay to assign image data to `canvas` with same width and height, but not okay to `toDataURL` for the canvas if it has a very big size. But Safari won't hang anyway, I can re-tap `input[type="file"]` to get next file since the empty `data:` outputted from previous one.